# Exporting external file template in IFS 9

Tags: ifs-erp

Is it possible to export an external file template from one database into another?
Just like you would export a custom object.
Best Regards Kresten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have found so far, the answer is no.
Best Regards Kresten